# How can I change the header color and language in django-import-export?

Tags: django, django-views, django-import-export, django-excel

I have a resource to export

```
class RequestResource(resources.ModelResource):
   class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ("service__name","user_name","user_address","user_number","user_email","region__name","tariff__name",'status','employee','comment','creation_date','type','connection_status')
```

How do I export names in the language I need?
[image]

Is it also possible to change colors in excel?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Where is `verbose_name` defined?  You cannot change the excel colors using django-import-export.  You would have to write a file using openpyxl for that.